# 404 error after page refresh using React.js with Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using Next.js Router to redirect to a url when button was clicked in React.js application. After page was refreshed, I am facing 404 error. Any solution to fix this ?

Comment: Please share your code for the button and how you are trying to make the redirect happen in code, so it will be easier to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: I am using like this. Router.push(`/dashboard?customerId=${customerId}`). Also, this issue is not reproducible in local env. Its in development env where package is installed.